# how to hide asp.net wizard's previous finish buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using wizard control in my asp.net web page. I add some steps in the wizard.I want to Hide previous and finish button from the wizard. I am not getting how to do this please tell me here is my source of wizard

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" BackColor="#F7F6F3" 
                BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" Height="85px" 
                onfinishbuttonclick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" Width="241px">
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" 
                    Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <NavigationButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
                    ForeColor="#284775" />
                <SideBarButtonStyle BorderWidth="0px" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="White" />
                <SideBarStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" BorderWidth="0px" Font-Size="0.9em" 
                    VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <StepStyle BorderWidth="0px" ForeColor="#5D7B9D" />
                <WizardSteps>
                    <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="About You">
                        Enter Your Name:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:WizardStep>
                    <asp:WizardStep runat="server" title="Fav Language" StepType="Finish">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem>C#</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>VB</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Css</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:WizardStep>
                    <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Ready">
                        <asp:Label ID="result" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:WizardStep>
                </WizardSteps>
            </asp:Wizard>
```

And my c# code is this

```
protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = "Your name is " + TextBox1.Text+"<br/>";
        result.Text += "<br/>Your Fav Language is " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    }
```

Experts Please tell me how can I do this ?

Comment: you can do it from Properties of wizard...

Comment: if you want to remove Finish button, then how would you finish the wizard O.o??

Answer (score 0):

Do you can try to create a css class 'Hidden' and change the class for the button previous .
But i'm not sure to understand why hide the "Finish button" ^^

```
/* CSS */
.hidden
{
  display:none;
}

/* C# */

 Wizard1.StepPreviousButtonStyle.CssClass = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used code for hiding a button yesterday.

```
private void Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
yourButton.Visible = !yourButton.Visible;
   }
```

I'm not sure if it'll disappear, if it doesn't, add alongside the code above, and it should work.

```
yourButton.Visible = false;
```

There is also options to do it with the CSS and jQuery. An example of what my my asp button looks like and where I get yourButton from.

```
<asp:Button ID="Closeform" runat="server" Text ="Hide PageState" OnClick="Close" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to a different question and came across this one.  I know it was asked a year ago, but it seems nobody ever gave a canonical answer.  For the ASP.NET wizard you can define the buttons associated with each step using the appropriate `NavigationTemplate` properties of the Wizard.  Below is an example using `Start`, `Step`, and `Finish`.  You can assign commands to each button, and then bind to the commands via the Wizard's event handlers (`OnNextButtonClick`, `OnPreviousButtonClick`, etc.).  In the `Next` and `Previous` handlers you will want to check which step you are on and act accordingly.  This is just scratching the surface of course.  You can cancel the navigation and customize the wizard's behavior much more.

### Example

.aspx:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="myWiz" runat="server" 
  OnNextButtonClick="myWiz_NextButtonClick"
  OnPreviousButtonClick="myWiz_PreviousButtonClick"
  OnFinishButtonClick="myWiz_FinishButtonClick">
    ...
    <StartNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" CssClass="NavBtn" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Next" />
    </StartNavigationTemplate>
    <StepNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" CssClass="NavBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Text="Previous" />
        <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" CssClass="NavBtn" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Next" />
    </StepNavigationTemplate>
    <FinishNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="FinishPreviousButton" CssClass="NavBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Text="Previous" />
        <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" CssClass="NavBtn" runat="server" CommandName="MoveComplete" Text="Finish" />
    </FinishNavigationTemplate>
    ...
</asp:Wizard>
```

---

.aspx.cs:

```
protected void myWiz_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e) {
    switch (e.CurrentStepIndex) {
        case 0:
            // on step 0, moving to step 1


        case 1:
           // on step 1, moving to step 2

        ...
    }        
  }

  protected void myWiz_PreviousButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e) {
    switch (e.CurrentStepIndex) {
        case 1:
            // on step 1, moving to step 0


        case 2:
           // on step 2, moving to step 1

        ...
    }   
  }

  protected void myWiz_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e) {
      // Regardless of step, validate and perform wizard wrap up
  }
```

---

For further reference, please check out the `Wizard Appearance` section of the [msdn page for the Wizard control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).